# Silverlight webclient downloadstringasync question

Tags: silverlight, asynchronous, windows-phone-7, webclient

I'm trying to put together a simple RSS feed reader in windows phone 7 but I'm struggling to understand how the async model works.

What I have is a helper class that when I pass it a URL will parse and build up a ViewModel object and return it. So what I am trying to acheive is this:

```
public static class FeedHelper
{
   public static FeedViewModel LoadFeed(string url)
   {
      //parse rss feed and return view model
   }
}
```

In the loadfeed method I would make a webclient object and build up the FeedViewModel. However because the WebClient's DownloadStringAsync is async and the result is returned to another method I can't figure out how I can return the FeedViewModel from my LoadFeed method.

Any examples or links to blog posts would be appreciated. I've done quite a bit of googling but can't find any examples of how I would approach this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return the ViewModel from your LoadFeed function because as you discovered, the call is async.

You have several choices, for ex. you could:

- make the LoadFeed method non-static and put it into a class (for ex. FeedRetriever)
- in the FeedRetriever class expose an event (or a command) "FeedLoaded"
- in your ViewModel repository subscribe to that event/command and take the ViewModel in the handler

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup the `WebClient`'s `DownloadStringCompleted` event handler to do the processing of the RSS feed. Note that `WebClient` returns on the UI thread and you are safe from cross-thread exceptions. Here is the snippet of code that goes into the LoadFeed method -

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompleteEventHandler(DownloadSettingsComplete);
wc.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
```

There are two sets of articles that will help you in buiding an RSS reader -

1. [Eugene Chaikin has built a simple RSS reader](http://www.eugenedotnet.com/WP7L8.ashx) that uses WebClient.
2. Dennis Delimarsky has a two part article on building a RSS reader - [part 1](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/building-rss-reader-windows), [part 2](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/building-rss-reader-windows-0)

HTH, indyfromoz

Comment: I don't think I explained my problem properly. I understand that the result comes back to the callback event. My issue, as with the first example you provided is that the UI is coupled with the code that is retrieving the feed data. I want the class which is returning the feed data to be independant from how I choose to persist/display it